# cleanly uninstall a broken jupyter nbextension

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

A while ago I installed `beakerx` and an update broke the installation. Every time I start IPython, a warning is shown. How can I cleanly get rid of the extension and this output?

```
  [IPKernelApp] WARNING | Error in loading extension: beakerx.autotranslation
    Check your config files in /Users/cls/.ipython/profile_default
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py", line 261, in init_extensions
        self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(ext)
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py", line 80, in load_extension
        mod = import_module(module_str)
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beakerx'
    [IPKernelApp] WARNING | Error in loading extension: beakerx_magics.kernel_magic
    Check your config files in /Users/cls/.ipython/profile_default
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py", line 261, in init_extensions
        self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(ext)
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py", line 80, in load_extension
        mod = import_module(module_str)
      File "/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beakerx_magics'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [following the uninstall directions](http://beakerx.com/documentation#tutorials-and-examples), I ran `grep -r beakerx *` in the root of my virtualenv and discovered the following debris:

```
etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json:      "beakerx": false
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['beakerx.autotranslation',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.kernel_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.groovy_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.clojure_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.kotlin_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.scala_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.sql_magic',
etc/ipython/ipython_config.py:'beakerx_magics.java_magic'
```

I removed offending lines from the above files, and the error messages disappeared.

For `ipython_config.py`

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
]
```

For `jupyter_notebook_config.json`

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "nbserver_extensions": {
    }
  },
  "KernelSpecManager": {}
}
```